# Is it possible to ensure a constexpr function is called at most once at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, c++20

As the title asks: Is it possible to ensure a constexpr function is called at most once at compile time?

This clearly won't be possible if the function is not constepxr; I could write a function that gets called whenever I press the space bar, so the compiler could never figure that out at compile time.

Comment: constexpr expressions/functions don't have side effects, so it does not matter how often they are called (except for runtime/performance). So why do you want to make sure a constexpr is evaluated only once?

Comment: @WernerHenze "So why do you want to make sure a constexpr is evaluated only once?" just curiosity and to find the boundaries of a language :-)

Comment: @rwols: The problem is that "called only once" is a meaningless concept for a `constexpr` function at compile time. It may literally be called one and a half time (!) - implementations can cache the evaluation of constexpr expressions, and this can include partial caching .

Comment: if you use precompiled headers and run `constexpr` function as: `constexpr auto result = function(args...);` in a header, then, maybe, compiler will only compute it once

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Short answer:* no, because `constexpr` functions cannot read/set external state. *(They can have internal state, but they still need to be "pure")*.

---

*Real answer:* probably yes, but it's a bad idea. There is a series of blog posts by *Filip Roséen* which covers the implementation of stateful `constexpr` functions by abusing `friend`ship and ADL:

- ["NON-CONSTANT CONSTANT-EXPRESSIONS IN C++"](http://b.atch.se/posts/non-constant-constant-expressions/) - [*(cached by Google)*](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lO7-AftL9mIJ:b.atch.se/posts/non-constant-constant-expressions/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)
- ["HOW TO IMPLEMENT A CONSTANT-EXPRESSION COUNTER IN C++"](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/) - [*(cached by Google)*](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3wqIj0l9XvYJ:b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)
- ["HOW TO IMPLEMENT A COMPILE-TIME META-CONTAINER IN C++"](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-meta-container/) - [*(cached by Google)*](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:heBoXSuNYCoJ:b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-meta-container/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)

The technique is very arcane and complicated. It is considered an abuse of features by CWG, [which is trying to make it **ill-formed** with issue #2118](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2118).

Comment: Those three articles are a good read, so +1 from me! You're probably right that nobody should ever use these techniques.

Comment: The (VERY SHOUTY) links are dead

Comment: @underscore_d: thanks, hopefully they'll be back soon. Added a Google cache link