lazy evaluate expensive local variable ONLY when needed within "if constexpr" WITHOUT run time if-else
I have to use variable v in 5-10 locations in a function.
From profiling, v is (relatively) very expensive to initialize.
How to initialize v only when needed?
It is unfortunate that it is a engine-code.
Adding some if-else will easily become bottleneck.
template<int flag1,int flag2,int flag3>  int expensiveFuncion(int a){
    /// Some expensive algorithm that has no side effect.
    /// Used only to initialize 'v' when needed.
    return a+flag1+flag2; ///: something that is a function of 'a' and flags
}
template<int flag1,int flag2,int flag3> void f(int& a){
    int v=expensiveFuncion<flag1,flag2,flag3>(a);
    if constexpr(flag1==0){ /// some complex condition on flags
        if constexpr(flag3==2){/// some complex condition on flags
            /// some complex algorithm that used 'v'
            
        }else if constexpr(flag2%2==0){/// some complex condition on flags
            if constexpr(flag3==3){/// some complex condition on flags
                 /// another different complex algorithm that used 'v'
            }else{
                 ///  NOT used 'v'
            }
        }
     
    }
    if constexpr(flag3==4){ ///: notice that 'v' may be used > 1 times
        /// used 'v'
    }
    ///... a lot of branches with different condition, 
    ///      only some branches use 'v'
 }


int main(){
    int k=0;
    f<0,2,4>(k);
}

My poor solution
Adding a flag near v like bool is_v_initialized=false .
When used ::-
if(!is_v_initialized){
    v=expensiveFuncion<flag1,flag2,flag3>();
    is_v_initialized = true;
}

Result :: if(!is_v_initialized) becomes a new bottleneck.
My poor solution 2
I insert initialization code to the top of algorithm, and query only when needed beforehand.
template<int flag1,int flag2,int flag3> void f(int& a){
    int v=-1234;

    ///vvv duplicated condition
    if constexpr(flag1==0 && flag3==2 
       ||  flag1==0 && ( !flag3==2  && flag2%2==0 && flag3 == 3)
       ||  flag3==4
        ///... 
    ){   
        v=expensiveFuncion<flag1,flag2,flag3>();  
        
       
    }
    ///^^^ duplicated condition

    ///  real algorithm is below
    if constexpr(flag1==0){ /// some complex condition on flags
        if constexpr(flag3==2){/// some complex condition on flags
           ....
 }

Result:: This is very migraine-induce to maintain, but works and super fast.
To show how strangely important this micro optimization is, the above code is around 1% of the lines of the whole program.   Frame-per-sec of the whole program using solution 2 = 1.25 of solution 1.

v is semantically const, make it static const. if(!is_v_initialized) becomes a new bottleneck. You are very irrationally pessimistic. This is not a bottleneck.

auto getV = [&]{ return expensiveFuncion<flag1,flag2,flag3>(a); }; and then auto v = getV(); in every narrowest scope that requires v?

@3CxEZiVlQ  :: It is very interesting.  I will research more about static const.   I agree that it is very strange.  After I measure frame-per-sec between solution 1 & solution 2, it is actually very different.

@user17732522 :: Thanks.  Sorry that I was not clear. v can be used > 1 times.   (I have edited the question. )

Then add std::optional<int> v; at the top and v = getV(); where you have the longer form currently in solution attempt 2. You will however be responsible to make sure that v will actually be initialized in every further use. That's already a problem in your second attempt though.

I suppose you could do some trickery with friend injection compile time state if you really want to have this automated. I wouldn't recommend it though.

@user17732522  :: Is it better than adding a new control flag and run 2 passes?    I could only think of a super ugly approach.

To me this looks like you are throwing too many unrelated things in one function. Separate the possible flows for the different flag settings into different functions.

@j6t :: This is the most ugly and convoluted function in my program.  I promise.

@cppBeginner I think you should be able to make v's type a class type wrapper with conversion from and to int. Have the conversion function to int inject a friend when instantiated. Make the initialization conditional on a template parameter. Then, wrap the whole function by another one that first instantiates the function without evaluating it, so that the friend is injected only if v is actually used. Then, check whether the friend was injected, and if so, call the function with or without the initialization enabled.

Make it multiple static const in every branch where it's used. Or make a function with that static const v and use a function.

@user17732522 :: Your solution sound so magic and I always love complex template answer.  I can feel its power.  May you post it, please? XD

@3CxEZiVlQ :: With static const, local static variable v inside a function can't be a function of a anymore.  I don't think that will work.  Please fix me if I am wrong.

@user17732522 :: Thanks.  Your solution is "Stateful metaprogramming via friend injection", isn't it?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/41939866/  and https://b.atch.se/posts/non-constant-constant-expressions/

It's probably (at least somewhat) difficult to avoid all possible ugliness.
But you're basically using v as a cache to minimize the number of invocations of expensiveFunction (including 0 invocations, if it's not used at all).
That being the case, it's pretty easy to keep the client code fairly clean by using a small proxy that acts as a cache on behalf of expensiveFunction:
#include <iostream>

template <int a>
int expensiveFunction(int b) { 
    return a / b;
}

template <int a>
int cache(int b) {
    static int ret;
    static int param;
    static bool needInit;

    if (needInit || b != param) {
        param = b;
        ret = expensiveFunction<a>(b);
        needInit = false;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() { 
    std::cout << cache<10>(5) << "\n";
    std::cout << cache<9>(5) << "\n";
    std::cout << cache<10>(5) << "\n"; // returns cached value
    std::cout << cache<9>(5) << "\n";  // also returns cached value
}

Result:
initializing, a = 10, b = 5
2
initializing, a = 9, b = 5
1
2
1

As it stands right now, you seem to count on all invocations of expensiveFunction being passed the same parameter value, so your cache may not need to store and verify the parameter value, just needInit (but since that can vary at runtime, it's not safe to assume that in general).

Thanks.  It is a nice attempt and can be used in many cases.  This solution would be even better if it doesn't remove multithread ability. +1

@cppBeginner: If threading is a concern, you can deal with that too, but especially for somebody calling themselves "cppBeginner", I didn't want to add complexity dealing with a topic they didn't mention...
